# Only show round numbers on x-axis in point plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

If I use the following code I end up with an overcrowded x-axis. I would like to show only every 10th number on the x axis. Meaning [0,10,...].
Any idea how to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

a = pd.DataFrame({'y':np.random.randn(100)})
a['time']=a.index

ax = sns.pointplot(x='time', y="y", data=a)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why are you using a point plot here? Is this a minimal example for a different use case? Can you state why a usual scatter plot would not work for you?

Comment: The use case is a time series, so i guess it needs to be a lineplot or sth of the kind.

Comment: Ok, so why does a line plot not work?

Comment: Well, I think it is kind of the same here. The pointplot has all dots connected by a line. I am happy with that part of the graph. The problem is that if the time-series is too long, the x-axis gets overcrowded and the labels become unreadable. Therefore I am trying to reduce the labels on the x-axis. Imagine the x-axis was made up of dates. And I only want to see 2016-01-01 and 2017-01-01 instead of every single month of the year

Answer (score 3):

You may decide not to use a pointplot at all. A usual lineplot seems to suffice.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

a = pd.DataFrame({'y':np.random.randn(100)})

plt.plot(a.index, a.y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now this gives ticks at steps of 20. The easiest option here would be to use

```
plt.xticks(range(0,101,10))
```

to get the steps of 10. Or equally possible,

```
 plt.gca().locator_params(nbins=11)
```

to devide the axis into 11 bins.

[image]

Of course the use of an appropriate locator would be equally possible.